# Register for your last action (.)

Tags: register, repeated-commands

Vim has a lot of useful registers from which you can access the contents of various actions. There's `":` for the last command in the command line, `"/` for the last search, `".` for the last insert, etc...

Is there a register that stores the last action performed (i.e. what gets done when I press <kbd>.</kbd>)?

Comment: Unfortunately, no... 

Comment: @filbranden RIP. You can leave that as an answer. I'll leave it for a few days to see if someone protests. If not, I'll accept it.

Comment: I think this is actually a duplicate https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/13429 or https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/15713

Comment: @statox I don't think it is. My question is not about editing it, neither about an alternative method to save the last action. It's specifically about the existence of a built-in register that automatically stores the contents of the `.` command. I think it's best to keep these links however, as the questions are related.

Comment: Using a register for this would actually be somewhat difficult, as registers are always global and the `.` is local to the buffer; it would have to introduce the concept of buffer-local registers. I think a function to access this would be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To quote *filbranden*'s comment:

> Unfortunately, no...